# How to change a variable value from within a function?

Tags: python, function, return

```
def Q1(score): #defines the first question
    print ("\n\n1) Question")
    print ("\nA) Option.")
    print ("\nB) Option")
    print ("\nC) Option.")

    ans = input("\nIs it A, B or C? ") #asks for the answer

    if ans.upper() == "B": #makes it uppercase if they entered lowercase
         print ("Correct!")
         score += 1 #adds one to the score
         return (score) #returns the score

Q1(score) #function is called
print (score) #score is printed
```

This is my code, no errors occur when I run it but when the "score" variable is returned the value is reset to 0, why? (Score is first defined above the first function, couldn't fit it in)

Comment: Read about the concepts on "passing by value" and "passing by reference" , and mutable/immutable objects in Python [for instance](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/is-python-call-by-reference-or-call-by-value/)  I'll edit the title since it's extremely misleading

Answer (score 1):

The Q1 function returns the result but you didn't save the result to a variable.
Do something like this:

```
score = Q1(score)
print(score)
```

Alternatively, directly print the returned value:

```
print(Q1(score))
```

Comment: When I do this and try and print score, print doesn't return a value

Comment: Do you mean nothing is printed on the console? The print function's return value isn't usually used.